# How to create a floormap using google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im working on a project to create a google map of an internal floorplan of my company's buildings. I dont want to use google's new indoor maps features as we dont want the floorplans available to the public. I was wanting to create an entirely custom map and just use the google maps engine and strip away the traditional world map tileset. Is this possible and how would I go about do it? Currently our floorplans are in an image file so a way to import those easily would be ideal.

Comment: I know it can be done. It is more a question of how. Ive seen others make maps like i am trying to make. Im just unsure of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem creating an app last summer. It does not look like Google Maps (at least at that time) allowed for custom map tiles. I ended up implementing my own Map function, however I used XML files to create colored maps. The functionality would be the same if you wanted to use images, however.

The only drawback is that the features do not have such things that are built in with Google Maps, like dropped pins, etc. due to the fact that it is a custom built module. The repo is on GitHub here: https://github.com/krmannix/SmartMart

The Android Activity that holds the map is located within SmartMart/SmartMart/src/com/example/searchcell3/MapListActivity.java